# Athena JSON storage and query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I plan to write S3 objects in JSON format. It is possible that over time, more keys will get added to the JSON objects(the objects that are written later in time).

I then plan to generate csv.gz files by running athena query on these S3 objects.

What I do not want to do is modify the athena table to keep adding column names as new keys get added into json. How do I deal with this? Is it possible that Athena can store the entire json in one string column and then conver that column's json into csv somehow when I query? Remember, I may not know all the column names upfront is the challenge as the json keys for future objects can have more keys then older objects

Comment: You don't "store data" in Amazon Athena. Rather, Amazon Athena is a **query engine** that can process data stored in Amazon S3. JSON is not an efficient way to store data for use with Amazon Athena -- is there a particular reason why you wish to use this format? For example, is it coming that way from a source system? If there are a large number of rows, you might consider converting the format into something to runs more efficiently (eg compressed Parquet). Please Edit your question to tell us more about your particular situation.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I edited the question. Let me know please

Comment: Amazon Athena does not "store data", however it can output data that is then stored in Amazon S3. For example, it can query one set of objects in Amazon S3 that are in JSON format and store the results in objects in Amazon S3 in `.csv.gz` format, yes. However, please note that when you write the query you will need to refer to the 'column' names (or attribute names in JSON), so you'll still need to know what attributes you wish to extract.